# Add layers from cartoDB browser to Android Application

Tags: java, android, cartodb

I have amap with three layers in cartoDB browser and I cant add the layers in my map in android App How can I add aKMZ layers (not base map) in CartoDB browser to Android App using java code to show All layer in App??
Can anyone help me?

The code for add base map

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Register the license so that CARTO online services can be used
    MapView.registerLicense(LICENSE,getApplicationContext());

    // Get 'mapView' object from the application layout
    mapView = (MapView) this.findViewById(R.id.mapView);

    // Add basemap layer to mapView
    CartoOnlineVectorTileLayer baseLayer = new CartoOnlineVectorTileLayer(CartoBaseMapStyle.CARTO_BASEMAP_STYLE_VOYAGER);
    mapView.getLayers().add(baseLayer);
}
```

Comment: welcome to SO. Please provide your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

My Project is indoor navigation System so I Need the layers in my map in cartoDB to show the level of building  in Android App

Answer (score 0):

Suggested solution would be to convert KMZ to GeoJSON beforehand with some tool. SDK itself does not do it. IN SDK you can then use GeoJSONGeometryReader to parse GeoJSON and add it finally to map as VectorLayer. My generic functions to do all this:

```
// usage: the file tpr-men.geojson is in assets folder of project
polygonGeoJSON(mapView,"tpr-men.geojson",android.graphics.Color.LTGRAY);

//helper function to read polygons from GeoJSON file, sets styles

private void polygonGeoJSON(MapView mapView, final String fileName, int color) {

    final Thread thread;// Initialize a local vector data source
    final LocalVectorDataSource source = new LocalVectorDataSource(baseProjection);

    // Initialize a vector layer with the previous data source
    VectorLayer vectorLayer = new VectorLayer(source);

    vectorLayer.setVectorElementEventListener(listener);

    // Add the clustered vector layer to the map
    mapView.getLayers().add(vectorLayer);



    LineStyleBuilder lsb = new LineStyleBuilder();
    lsb.setColor(new Color(color));
    lsb.setWidth(0.5f);
    lsb.setLineJoinType(LineJoinType.LINE_JOIN_TYPE_NONE);
    lsb.setLineEndType(LineEndType.LINE_END_TYPE_NONE);

    PolygonStyleBuilder polygonBuilder = new PolygonStyleBuilder();
    polygonBuilder.setColor(new Color(color & 0xbbffffff)); // a bit transparent
   //polygonBuilder.setLineStyle(lsb.buildStyle());
    final PolygonStyle style = polygonBuilder.buildStyle();

    // As the file to load is rather large, we don't want to block our main thread
    thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        @Override
        public void run() {


            try {

                // Read GeoJSON, parse it using SDK GeoJSON parser
                GeoJSONGeometryReader reader = new GeoJSONGeometryReader();

                // Set target projection to base (mercator)
                reader.setTargetProjection(baseProjection);
                Log.d("log","Starting load from .geojson");

                // Read features from local asset
                String json = loadJSONFromAsset(fileName);
                Log.d("log","Finished load from .geojson");

                FeatureCollection features = reader.readFeatureCollection(json);
                Log.d("log","Finished parsing of geojson, loaded objects: "+features.getFeatureCount());

                source.addFeatureCollection(features,style);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d("log","Finished load from geojson");

        }
    });

    thread.start();


}

// general helper function to read file to String
private String loadJSONFromAsset(String fileName) throws IOException {

    InputStream is = getAssets().open(fileName);
    int size = is.available();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    is.read(buffer);
    is.close();

    return new String(buffer, "UTF-8");

}
```